# I trying to stream screen to multiple sources with ffmpeg and got error

Tags: ffmpeg, tee

My command

```
ffmpeg -thread_queue_size 1024 -f x11grab -draw_mouse 0 -video_size 1920x1080 -i :99.0+0,0 -f alsa -i pulse -channels 2 -c:a aac -b:a 160k -ar 44100 -threads 8 -c:v libx264 -x264-params nal-hrd=cbr -profile:v baseline -framerate 30 -level:v 4.2 -vf format=yuv420p -b:v 1000k -maxrate 1500k -minrate 1000k -bufsize 8000k -g 60 -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -f tee -flags +global_header -map 0:v -map 1:a "[f=flv:onfail=ignore]rtmp://stream1|[f=flv:onfail=ignore]rtmp://stream2"
```

Error in console:

```
[NULL @ 0x55aaf9a54bc0] Unable to find a suitable output format for '"[f=flv:onfail=ignore]rtmp://strea1
[tee @ 0x55aaf96f3200] Slave muxer #0 failed, aborting.
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
Error initializing output stream 0:1 --
```

Comment: with 1 stream and without tee it works correctly

Answer (score 1):

```
ffmpeg -thread_queue_size 1024 -f x11grab -draw_mouse 0 -video_size 1920x1080 -i :99.0+0,0 -f alsa -i pulse -channels 2 -c:a aac -b:a 160k -ar 44100 -threads 8 -c:v libx264 -x264-params nal-hrd=cbr -profile:v baseline -framerate 30 -level:v 4.2 -vf format=yuv420p -b:v 1000k -maxrate 2500k -minrate 800k -bufsize 8000k -g 60 -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -map 0:v -map 1:a -f tee -flags +global_header [f=flv:onfail=ignore:flvflags=no_duration_filesize]rtmp://stream1|[f=flv:onfail=ignore:flvflags=no_duration_filesize]rtmp://stream2
```

problem was with quotes